# Efficient query to choose books not previously issued

Tags: mysql

Imagine :
Members table with 10,000+ records 
Books table with 10,000+ records

What will be best approach to select
RANDOM member and allot RANDOM book to him
WHICH is not previously allotted to him ?

Issuance table and query I have designed to store member/book allotment
and return new record is very slow.
Issuance table will become very fat over the time, naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RANDOM()` is very slow. Try adding a "random_order" column to your tables and assigning a random number to each row with the `RANDOM()` function. Make sure those columns are indexed, and then after that you can use a query to select the maximum random_order item. Since the random column is random, the maximum is not meaningful except to "take one book off the top" of the list of recommendations. This method will recommend books in the same order for every member, but it will be a random order. You could update the `random_order` column daily to shuffle it.

How to prevent getting the same book twice in a row? You need to keep track of which books have been recommended to which member and exclude them from the MAX() calculation.

Table: member_books_recommended

columns: member_id, book_id (InnoDB tables with foreign key to the parent tables, on delete/update cascade)

Whenever you make a recommendation, you run this SQL to record that you've recommended this book to this member:

```
INSERT INTO member_books_recommended (`member_id`, `book_id`) VALUES ($member_id,$book_id); // assuming PHP code for the member id, book id
```

When you get the next recommendation, you use the table of previously recommended books to exclude results from your list of recommended books:

```
SELECT `book_id` FROM `books_table` WHERE `book_id` NOT IN (SELECT `book_id` FROM `member_books_recommended` WHERE `member_id` = $member_id) ORDER BY `random_column` DESC LIMIT 1; // again PHP code for $member_id
```

I hope that helps.